# SuperResolution and Laplacian Term

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, convolution

I'm writing a program that allows to preform the SuperResolution algorithm. In the book, on the way of restoration, they uses the discrete Laplacian operator. I must somehow multiply the matrix (my image) by this Laplacian operator. So, i have to represent this operator as a matrix, but i cant imagine HOW?

The text from the book:

> The Laplacian is a second-derivative term, but for discrete data, it
>   can be approximated by a single convolution with a mask of form:

[image]

> The operator preforms this convolution as matrix multiplication. It has the form like below  (blank represents zeroes).

[image]

P.S. sorry for my English! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to apply the 3x3 convolution kernel to your image, e.g. in pseudo-code:

```
for i = 1 to M - 1
    for j = 1 to N - 1
        img_out[i][j] = 4 * img[i][j] - img[i-1][j] - img[i+1][j] - img[i][j-1] - img[i][j+1]
```

where `img` is the input image, `M` is the number of rows, `N` is the number of cols, `img_out` is the convolved output image.

Note that the border pixels in `img_out` are undefined.

Comment: Paul, thx a lot, now is much more clearer! 

But i still can't get one thing. I've never worked with the images before, but i suggest each pixel in my image must be a structure, consisting of three fields ( Red, Green, and Blue colors ).

As far as i understand, i should write
img_out[i][j].red = 4 * img[i][j].red - img[i-1][j].red - img[i+1][j].red - img[i][j-1].red - img[i][j+1].red 

and repeat it for the other two fields, or am i mistaken?

Comment: Most image processing algorithms are described in terms of a grey scale (i.e. intensity) image. But yes, you can probably get away with applying the algorithm to each colour plane separately as you describe.

Comment: I looked at the book again, the formula is http://i.stack.imgur.com/igjAl.jpg
as it said Qt*Q is the Laplacian term, lambda is just a number, but A - is the united matrix of image transformation. The width of this matrix is MxN and the height might be varying, (M and N is the size of the image).

So, i must somehow scale this 3x3 kernel to the suitable size. Like in the last image in my first post.

I cant find the dependency (if i found the right word)

Comment: I don't think you need to scale the kernel - the Laplacian term is most likely the output image from the above convolution, i.e. MxN image convolved with 3x3 Laplacian kernel.

Comment: To be honest, i didnt completely understand u, but i think u didnt understand me. Look at the formula, i have to add Matrix A (MxN) with Laplacian operator (3x3 matrix). To perform that, i have to make their size the same.

Comment: I think you are confusing the 3x3 Laplacian *convolution kernel* with the Laplacian *term*, which is an MxN image convolved with the 3x3 kernel as per my pseudo code above. The `L` in 2.3.7 is just the convolution expressed as a matrix multiplication, but you don't need to do this explicitly.

Comment: hmm. I can apply "your" code to the image or multiply the image by the 2.3.7 and I will get the same result, right?

Anyway, the main problem remains the same: according to the formula http://i.stack.imgur.com/igjAl.jpg i have to add matrix A with the operator L (2.3.7). But how can i get L?